# Prevent modal to close when click on the background [Vuejs]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using **[vue-js-modal](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal)** library and following the same steps in the documentation, but I need to implement that when the modal opened the user cannot close the modal when he clicks on the background behind the modal.

In the documentation written that use property **clickToClose**, but when I use it inside the modal error message appears for me:

```
<modal name="image-modal" clickToClose="false"></modal>
```

Error message:

```
Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "clickToClose". Expected Boolean, got String.
```

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clickToClose="false"` sets the `clickToClose` prop to the string `"false"`.

You need to use [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) to bind to an arbitrary JavaScript expression:

```vue
<modal name="image-modal" :clickToClose="false"></modal>
```

In the above snippet, `false` is evaluated as JavaScript code instead of a string.

Answer (score 6):

**Subsequently for those using bootstrap-vue:**
add "no-close-on-backdrop" and set it to "true".

```
<b-modal id="modal_id" :no-close-on-backdrop="true">
```

Comment: this question is not about bootstrap, it's about vue-js-modal

Answer (score 1):

The kebabCase in clickToClose may not work. This works for me

```
<modal name="image-modal" v-bind:click-to-close="false"></modal>
```

Comment: This is the actual answer. Alternatively you can do the shorthand: `:click-to-close="false"`

Answer (score -2):

While using vue-js Modal (). There is a property in Modal called backdrop. You should use this

```js
:close-on-backdrop="false" :close-on-esc="false"
```

In your Modal tag.

Comment: Hello. The answer would be better if you format the code properly and, idealy, put the full modal code.